# How to stylize terminal's container with "add new tab" and list of tabs items?

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

I'm talking about this container:

[image: image @ imgur]

What is the CSS id/class/tag for it? I've tried to find it in gnome-terminal source, but I'm unfamiliar with C++.

Comment: And I'd like to know how you styled the Terminal in the first place. It looks awesome. :)

Comment: @grooveplex I'm using [Flatabulous](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous) theme and working on a fix for [this issue](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous/issues/66) (that's why my tabs are dark, not light as in the master branch). 
I've added some paddings to the Terminal using a popular method from the Internet. 
My shell is zsh and PS1 is `%{$fg[green]%}➜ %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%}`

Comment: gnome-terminal is written in C, not C++ :P

Comment: Gtk+ has a built-in inspector (similarly to many popular web browsers). Search for this on the web to figure out how to enable/use it. I hope this inspector will help you quickly locate the properties you're looking for.

Comment: @egmont there's no way to use Gtk Inspector for Terminal, because Ctrl+Shift+D just closes it and Ctrl+Shift+I inserts an indentation. If I run gnome-terminal-server with GTK_DEBUG=interactive, it will open Gtk Inspector but there will be no terminal window visible in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Defman After exporting `GTK_DEBUG`, following the steps at https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/Debugging run `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server --app-id x.y` and then within 10 seconds run `gnome-terminal --app-id x.y`.

Comment: @egmont unfortunately this doesn't help at all, I can only see Terminal's GMenu in Inspector's hierarchy.

Comment: @Defman Hmmm, it definitely worked in Xenial beta a couple of months ago. Now in Xenial final I also only see the GMenu. Sorry, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @Defman I figured it out :) The problem is that the Inspector is opened before the terminal window, and it takes a snapshot of the app's state and doesn't refresh. Maybe there's a way to refresh the snapshot, I don't know. Or, if you could get the hotkey working then sure it'd be okay, again, I don't know how to fix the hotkey. What worked for me: I recompiled gnome-terminal with --enable-debug, and so a Help->Inspector menu entry appeared which opens the inspector whenever you wish (and GTK_DEBUG isn't needed anymore).

Comment: @egmont hmm I'll try to rebuild gnome-terminal, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

It's `TerminalWindow .notebook .button` . This works for me:

```
@define-color bg-grey #222;
@define-color active-grey #333;
@define-color border-grey #555;

TerminalWindow .notebook {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
  border: 1px solid @border-grey;
  background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
  background-color: shade(@bg-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook .button,
TerminalWindow .notebook .button:active {
    padding: 2 2 2 10;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0;
}
```